# discord bot scripts not working as it should in vps?

Tags: python, discord.py, vps, ubuntu-20.04

I have uploaded my discord bot python script to my vps, and it's not working like it should.
I get the error

```
File "/root/cogs/zaidimas.py", line 426, in atnaujinti
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE misijos SET laikasmisija = {laikutis-3} WHERE userid                        ={zaidikas}")                                                                                     
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

whereas in windows I don't get this error, this is the code that's giving the error

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=3.0)
async def atnaujinti(self):
    db=sqlite3.connect('misija.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT userid FROM misijos")
    for zaidejas in cursor.fetchall():
        zaidikas=zaidejas[0]
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT laikasmisija FROM misijos WHERE userid={zaidikas}")
        laikas=cursor.fetchone()
        laikutis=laikas[0]
        db.commit()
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE misijos SET laikasmisija = {laikutis-3} WHERE userid={zaidikas}")
    db.commit()
```

after I put laikutis and zaidimas in int( ) the error dissapears, but every other line of code needs to be changed like that too, I never got these errors in windows and the code was working fine.

The vps is ubuntu 20.04, python 3.9.1, discord py 1.6
i run the code with 'python3.9 taisykliuBot.py' (taisykliuBot.py is the main script)
what could be wrong here or will i need to go and change all the values in the script?

EDIT: My point is that the same code compiles perfectly in windows, but on ubuntu it gives me errors. Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: I think the error pretty much speaks for itself, you're trying to subtrack an int from a string. It makes sense that if you convert it to an int it works fine

Comment: but as I said, in windows this error doesn't appear, the code is about 6000 lines long with a lot of sql queries, the error happens only in the vps, is there a way to make it dissapear without changing every single variable?

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to an int like what Łukasz said.

```py
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE misijos SET laikasmisija = {int(laikutis)-3} WHERE userid={zaidikas}")
```